# I am new to dateformatters, picked date and time from datepicker and need to converted to required from before sending to the server

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting, swift5

picked date and time from datepicker and need to converted to required from before sending to the server.
not able to convert to the required from.

```
func convertToUTC(dateToConvert:String) -> String {
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"

      let convertedDate = formatter.date(from: dateToConvert)
      formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
      return formatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
         }

requred date form is Sat Aug 1 2020 23:38:56 GMT+0530
```

Comment: If you are using a date picker why do you need to input a string?

Comment: I have two textfields,one for only date and other for time,I have send these both combined strings to the server.         ex - I got date as "Aug 2,2020" and time "23:38:56 " and want to convert to the format  "Sat Aug 1 2020 23:38:56 GMT+0530".@LeoDabus

Comment: Is your API with your server locked into that format? Generally we use [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or RFC3339 format produced by [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter), namely `2020-08-01T13:42:00Z`. And if you tell it to include milliseconds, it would be `2020-08-01T13:42:00.123Z`. This is the _lingua franca_ for dates over the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create two date formats, one to parse the input date string and another to convert the date to your server date format:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let inputDate: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    static let serverDate: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xxxx"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
}
```

---

```
func convertToServer(input: String) -> String? {
    guard let date = Formatter.inputDate.date(from: input) else { return nil }
    return Formatter.serverDate.string(from: date)
}

convertToServer(input: "Sat Aug 1 2020 23:38:56.123Z") // "Sat Aug 1 2020 20:38:56 GMT-0300"
```